# Ubuntu as host on MacbookPro 13 2011 - BIOS - Hyper-V

Tags: vmware-player

my computer is an old MacBookPro 13" from 2011. I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on it as the only OS on the device, and i encrypted the drive.
I can do all i want with virtual machines, even run Windows 11 pro on it, not smoothly but works...Now i wanna push even further and try to install Ubuntu as Windows-Subsystem-Linux (WSL 2), but it says that i must enable Hyper-V in the Bios.
Being, my computer, a MacBookPro, for my understanding, doesn't have a Bios, and anyway i should access the VM bios...i tried rebooting the Windows VM and pressing F2 i can get in the menu but no option for the Bios configuration, and also from the booted VM, "advanced feature" -> reboot -> etc, i cannot get the proper bios with the possibility to change any setting at all...

Anybody has ever had the same problem?

Thanks for your time in advance.